# Implementing an Entry Widget with ScrollableFrame in CustomTkinter and Handling Outside Click Event Using

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm working on creating an entry widget that, upon being clicked, will display a ScrollableFrame with a list of options in radio button form using CustomTkinter. Additionally, when clicked elsewhere outside the ScrollableFrame, it should disappear.

Despite multiple attempts to modify the code, the ScrollableFrame with the list of options does not appear when clicking the entry widget. The issue remains unresolved despite efforts to rectify it.

Note: This is a portion of the whole code

here's my code

```
#imports
#------------------------------
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter import ttk


#-------------------------------
def user_window():
    #destroy the user login window
    #window.destroy()

    #main window
    user_window = ctk.CTk()

    #geometry
    user_window.geometry("900x900")
    
    #title
    user_window.title("Sadiq And Antony's Airlines")

    #ticket
    search_ticket_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(user_window,corner_radius=15,width=500,height=250,fg_color="gray")
    search_ticket_frame.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)

    #within the frame
    #from
    from_label = ctk.CTkLabel(search_ticket_frame, text="From (Departure)", font=("Arial", 20))
    from_label.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=20)

    #separator 1
    sep1 = ttk.Separator(search_ticket_frame, orient="vertical")
    sep1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns",rowspan=2)

    #to
    to_label = ctk.CTkLabel(search_ticket_frame, text="To(Arrival)", font=("Arial", 20))
    to_label.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10,pady=20)
    
    #separator 2
    sep2 = ttk.Separator(search_ticket_frame, orient="vertical")
    sep2.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="ns",rowspan=2)

    #departure date
    d_date = ctk.CTkLabel(search_ticket_frame,text="Departure Date",font=("Arial", 20))
    d_date.grid(row=0,column=4,padx=10,pady=20)

    #separator 3
    sep3 = ttk.Separator(search_ticket_frame, orient="vertical")
    sep3.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky="ns",rowspan=2)

    #arrivak date
    a_date = ctk.CTkLabel(search_ticket_frame,text="Arrival Date",font=("Arial", 20))
    a_date.grid(row=0,column=6,padx=10,pady=20)

    #separator 4
    sep4 = ttk.Separator(search_ticket_frame, orient="vertical")
    sep4.grid(row=0, column=7, sticky="ns",rowspan=2)

    #Travellers
    n_pass = ctk.CTkLabel(search_ticket_frame,text="Travellers",font=("Arial", 20))
    n_pass.grid(row=0,column=8,padx=10,pady=20)

    #separator 5
    sep5 = ttk.Separator(search_ticket_frame, orient="vertical")
    sep5.grid(row=0, column=9, sticky="ns",rowspan=2)

    #class
    class_label = ctk.CTkLabel(search_ticket_frame,text="Class",font=("Arial", 20))
    class_label.grid(row=0,column=10,padx=10,pady=20)


    #the countries frame
    def display_countries(event):
        # Create the scrollable frame for countries
        scrollable_frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(user_window, corner_radius=10, width=200, height=200)
        scrollable_frame.pack(expand= True, anchor=tk.W)

        countries = ["Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3", "Country 4", "Country 5", "Country 6", "Country 7", "Country 8", "Country 9", "Country 10"] #test
        for country in countries:
            ctk.CTkRadioButton(scrollable_frame, text=country, font=("Arial", 16)).pack(fill=tk.X)


    #searchbars
    #searchbar for from
    s1 = ctk.CTkEntry(search_ticket_frame,placeholder_text="Your Choice",font=("Arial",20),width=200)
    s1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=30)

    #when clicked displays the listof countrues
    s1.bind("<<Button-1>>",display_countries)   
    
    
    
    user_window.mainloop()

user_window()
```

Comment: My apologies, I have edited the question again

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually want it to look like, but the code above shows a user input text field. There's no Button that shows up. If you actually want a Button, you would need that. Or an OptionMenu if you want a drop-down menu. Not sure if that helps.